# Pyspark: Regex_replace commas between quotes

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm struggling with replacing with `regexp_replace` in Pyspark. I have to following string column:

```
"1233455666, 'ThisIsMyAdress, 1234AB', 24234234234"
```

A better overview of the string:

| Id | Address | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1233455666 | 'ThisIsMyAdress, 1234AB' | 24234234234 |

The total string that I receive and process is comma separated, like the example in the beginning. Unfortunately I can't change this format of delivered data. To handle the data well I want to replace the comma between the quotes with nothing.

The only requirement is using `regexp_replace`.

I've tried the code below, and many more. But with these code the comma separation will break as well. Then the string is one big string with removed comma's.

```
.withColumn("ColCommasRemoved" , regexp_replace( col("X"), "[,]", ""))
```

which gave me this output:

```
"1233455666 'ThisIsMyAdress 1234AB' 24234234234"
```

The output what I want to achieve:

```
"1233455666, 'ThisIsMyAdress 1234AB', 24234234234"
```

Comment: Without a UDF, it would be difficult to avoid multiple edge cases that you will get if you use `regexp_replace( col("X"), "('[^',]*),([^']*')", "$1$2" )`

Comment: Commas are perfectly valid in comma-separated files, as long as they are quoted.  Why do you need to do this?

Comment: In a later step we split, based on the comma's, to columns for the dataframe. That process break now when having that comma in there @TimRoberts. And yes, maybe the solution isn't designed in a perfect way, but it's kind of legacy script.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the CSV module (maybe with a stringIO ojbect) to parse these lines using the standard mechanism?

Comment: My main goal is to replace the comma inside the quotes. Tried your solution in the current solution, unfortunately @blackbishop

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew unfortunately your proposed solution doesn't work in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `regexp_replace`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("1233455666, 'ThisIsMyAdress, 1234AB', 24234234234",)], ["X"])

result = df.withColumn(
    "ColCommasRemoved",
    F.split(F.regexp_replace("X", ",(?=[^']*'[^']*(?:'[^']*'[^']*)*$)", ""), ",")
).select(
    F.col("ColCommasRemoved")[0].alias("ID"),
    F.col("ColCommasRemoved")[1].alias("Address"),
    F.col("ColCommasRemoved")[2].alias("Code")
)

result.show()
#+----------+------------------------+------------+
#|ID        |Address                 |Code        |
#+----------+------------------------+------------+
#|1233455666| 'ThisIsMyAdress 1234AB'| 24234234234|
#+----------+------------------------+------------+
```

Or if you want to split directly the original column by `,` and ignore those inside quotes:

```
result = df.withColumn(
    "split",
    F.split(F.col("X"), ",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)")
)

result.show(truncate=False)
#+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
#|X                                                |split                                                |
#+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
#|1233455666, 'ThisIsMyAdress, 1234AB', 24234234234|[1233455666,  'ThisIsMyAdress, 1234AB',  24234234234]|
#+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This solution works in 99 times of the 100, but when an address have for example an apostrophe `12345566,'ABC 't ThisIsMyAdress', 24234234234 ` the regex stop working due the single quote before the T in the address name.

If I replace in a step earlier te single quote, then this logic break. I've tried with this logic:


.withColumn("ColReplaceSingleQuote" , F.regexp_replace( col("value"), "[\']", '"' ))
.withColumn("ColCommasRemoved", F.regexp_replace("ColReplaceSingleQuote", ",(?=[^']*'[^']*(?:'[^']*'[^']*)*$)", ""))

Is there an easy option to apply this in the proposed solution?

Comment: @haassiej you can try replacing them in your earlier step using this `F.regexp_replace("X", "(?<!,)(?<!')'(?=.*')", "")`